# Creating textarea and multiple elements on click for replying to a comment

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Currently, I have a PHP script that fetches comments from database (com_text, name, etc) and I echo them and for each result, I also echoing a div with a hidden textarea (from CSS) and multiple input fields `(type='hidden')`, then on a button click (reply) I change the div with the textarea from hidden to in-line so the user can type and reply to a comment. 
Ex:

```
foreach($result as $r){
<div class='comments'>
echo"<p>$r['com_text']</p>";
<button> reply <button>
etc
</div>

<div class="reply_container>
<form>
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="hidden value="value_from_database" name="">
<input type="hidden value="" name="">
<button type="submit></button>
</form>
</div>
}
```

You get the idea for each comment I also create a hidden textarea to let people reply.

My question is: can I do something like this dynamically so I don't have to create this for every comment? Or is there a better way?

The idea that I have is to create another PHP script that appends something like this with Ajax, is that the way to go?

Thank you.

Comment: I would think its either very simple or not so simple, depending on how you plan the replies to the comments are to be stored, sorted and re-displayed.

Comment: So long as you can have some sort of unique identifier attached to each comment, it shouldn't be to complex. I might use a slightly different structure for this, but it seems pretty trivial.

Comment: @I. R. R. The comments are stored with id, and parent_id NULL, and the replies parent_id is populate with the id of the comment they belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have a single reply div, and multiple comments. Clicking on any .comment div will trigger my listener, which will populate the relevant fields in the reply div and show it. Is this something like you're looking for?

```js
$(".comments-pane").on("click", ".comment", function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var elID = $(this).attr("id");
  var elText = $(this).text();
  
  $(".reply_container")
     .find("h3")
       .text("Your reply to "+elText).end()
     .find(".comment_id")
       .val(elID).end()
     .show();
   });
```

```css
.reply_container {
  display: none;
}
.comment {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comments-pane">
  <div class="comment" id="4042311">
    The first one
  </div>
  <div class="comment" id="4042313">
    A follow-up comment
  </div>
  <div class="comment" id="4042317">
    Yet a third comment.
  </div>
</div>
  
  
<div class="reply_container">
  <h3></h3>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="comment_id">
<input type="text" value="" name="reply_text">
<button type="submit">Reply</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think something like this is exactly what i am looking for, i'll try it ASAP and i'll get back to you, Thank you.

Comment: Cool. best of luck.